# I'm using $.ajax I need to send it to a class in php function

Tags: php, jquery

I need to send the value name to a method insert_user php.

What I want to do is basically put that **$.ajax** script inside a function and call the PHP function from javascript.

```
var name=$.trim($('#nombre').val());

$.ajax({
        url:"estados.php",
        type:'POST',
});

<?php
class work
{
     public function insert_user()
     {
        $name=$_GET["nombre"]; 
        $sql="INSERT INTO prueba values(
        null,'$name')";
        $res=mysql_query($sql,Conectar::con());      
     }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**SCRIPT**

```
$.ajax({
    url:"estados.php",
    type:'POST',
    data:{nombre:name},
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    class work
    {
        public function insert_user($name)
        {
            $sql="INSERT INTO prueba values(
            null,'$name')";
            $res=mysql_query($sql,Conectar::con());      
        }
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST["nombre"]))
    {
        $wk= new work();
        $wk->insert_user($_REQUEST["nombre"]);
    }
?>
```